# MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559): Failed to handle method call

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

this is a login app i added the user in the firebase. All setup but whenever i tried to do login, this error occurred :

> MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559): Failed to
>   handle method call

i added these dependencies

my pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.7.0
```

android/gradle.properties

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
   }
```

android/app/gradle.properties

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //at the end
```

> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559): Failed to
>   handle method call
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:302)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:89)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:201)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:88)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:219)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:328)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6364)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
>
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(31559):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:937) I/flutter
>   (31559): Given String is empty or null

Comment: Given this message "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null", you are passing in an empty string or null somewhere. Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful) it'll be hard to say more.

Comment: i solved it i was passing forms value in the email and password field but what i need to do  is passing the email and password in the value

Answer (score 0):

this error happens because you have not enabled google sign in and sign in with email and password in your firebase console account try to enable it from your firebase console.
how to enable it: login to your console click on the particular app you want to use the sign in for and click authentication  and click sign-in method  now toggle on the sign-in options you want thanks I believe this works for you
before you do this make sure u have add the firebase file to your application i mean the google-service.json file